# Decode installer made by install4j

Tags: install4j

I want to build an installer as Jira by install4j but they have some custom actions in the installer. I am wondering that is there a method to decode installer or reserve an installer made by install4j to install4j project file? So I can refer those to make my own.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. The installer is a binary artifact and while it does have a config file in `.install4j/i4jparams.config` it does not contain all required information for reversing it.